# How to find the n-th word in a file (Linux Shell)

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell

I'm trying to write a Shell Script that takes a file name and a number, and prints out the n-th word in the file. Is there any simple command that can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
tr '\n' ' ' < "$1" | cut -d' ' -f$2
```

Then run:

```
./script.sh filename.txt 30
```

Assumptions: words are separated by single spaces, words do not contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with punctuation and multiple spaces try something like

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -e 's/[[:punct:]]*//g;s/[[:space:]]\+/\n/g' < $1 | sed $2q;d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v var=$2 '{print $var}' < $1
```

Run example:

```
./script.sh filename.txt 30
```